# Python "ImportError: cannot import name" issue

Tags: python, import, importerror

I'm having trouble importing a variable from my `config/__init__.py` file.

My directory looks like:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base_config.py
│   │   ├── log_config.py
│   │   └── output_config.py
│   ├── script.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have `from config.output_config import output_data`. This file also contains a line `BUCKET = ...`

In my `output_config.py` file I have `from config import BUCKET`, which is them used in the function `output_data()`.

In `script.py` I have `import config` and a call to `config.output_data()`

When I run script.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../src/config/output_config.py", line 15, in <module>
    from config import BUCKET
  File ".../src/config/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from config.output_config import output_data
  File ".../src/config/output_config.py", line 15, in <module>
    from config import BUCKET
ImportError: cannot import name 'BUCKET'
```

It seems like my issue is probably polluting the name space (..and making a circular reference..?), but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. It's my understanding that the `__init__.py` file is best used to import other config files, but then I'm not sure how to get my variable `BUCKET` into the `output_config.py` file where I need it. Would appreciate help resolving the issue and understanding best practices for structuring projects as it relates to importing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say get that variable BUCKET to a different python file or a settings.py if it is a settings or constant as you are incurring in circular imports because of it.

**Update from comments:**

Create a `settings.py` or `constants.py` file and put the settings/constants there, and try to avoid any imports in `__init__.py` unless it is a standard library import to avoid any potential circular reference on imports.

One thing to remember is that anything you put in `__init__.py` is loaded whenever you import any module in that package so you need to be careful what you put there and try to keep it short.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My follow up then is where should constants like this live? `__init__.py` also has a bunch of other constants imported from environment variables, and I'd like all the "set-up" stuff to live together if possible.

Comment: create a settings.py or constants.py file and put them there, and try to avoid any imports in that file unless it is a standard library import to avoid any potential circular reference on imports.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up moving it to `base_config.py` and it's working fine. Per your recommendation, do you usually put that settings.py file in the config folder? Or somewhere else?

Comment: I usually put constants in a settings.py file but there are many ways.  There are also nice libraries like openstack oslo.config that handle configuration plus argument parsing.  One thing to remember is that anything you put in `__init__.py` is loaded whenever you import any module in that package so you need to be careful what you put there and try to keep it short.

Answer (score 0):

I also got that error message using Python 3.7 on pythonanywhere. Turns out that I had uploaded the source module twice, one of them on my user folder. Modules should only be placed on the project folder.